# 2 variables in SQL Statement PHP/SQLite

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web, sqlite

I have an AJAX request, which passes two variables

```
data: {name:name,ubu:ubu}
```

and I fetch them in PHP as

```
$name= $_GET['name'];
$ubu= $_GET['ubu'];
```

and insert them into a SQL-Statement for my SQLite database

```
$query = "SELECT '$ubu' FROM '$name'";
```

But the first variable refuses to work. If I replace the '$ubu' in the query with the rowname, it works like a charm, and I can change the $name from the AJAX side.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: Well, just as I posted this, I found a way:

```
$query = "SELECT "  .$ubu. " FROM '$name'";
```

Probably not the best way to do it, but at least it works now :)

Comment: you are saying `$ubu` is an variable and replaced it as a field name right?

Comment: This makes you vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: For my site it probably doesn't matter, but what would be a better way to do it?

Comment: Check the value against a whitelist of allowed columns before using it in the sql statement (accounts for both `$name` and `$ubu`)

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. I'll add it to my site :)